# How can I have Win98 style buttons?

Tags: delphi, button

I am using Delphi 10.3 Community Edition and I'm on Windows 7.

By default the buttons generated by Delphi are (of course) Win7 style.

How can I have "old-style" Win98 buttons (see attached picture).

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It would surely be better to let the user choose through compat settings.

Comment: Is this a user request? Or is this application demonstrating outdated technology? Because if you're adding some option to choose "style", you're much better off leaving it up to the user to configure this system-wide. The buttons are drawn by Windows anyway, however Windows decides to draw them. As David mentions in his answer, disabling runtime themes would give you what you want, but then the user couldn't enable them if they wanted to.

Comment: The image implies you're asking about whole window while the question asks specifically about buttons. Which is it?

Comment: Many thanks to all. I want the windows (form) to be Win7 style and the buttons to be Win98. I unchecked "enable run themes" and it worked!

Comment: Is it possible also to see win98 buttons during design phase (within the IDE) before compiling and running?

Comment: I tried this but it did not work: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Disabling_Themes_in_the_IDE_and_in_Your_Application

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck the [enable runtime themes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Application_Options#Manifest_File_.28Windows_Only.29) option.